# Run vpython in python3 without jupyter possible?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, vpython

In Python2.7 all my visual scripts were running fine. When I use Python3.5 I get the error message:

```
get_ipython().kernel.comm_manager.register_target('glow', GlowWidget)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'kernel'
```

When I google the error message people say that you should use the jupyter notebook. But is it possible to run my old scripts without jupyter?

Comment: What versions of ipython are you using with both 2.7 and 3.5?

Comment: According to [vpython.org](http://vpython.org/), there is 'Classic VPython' and 'Jupyter VPython'. I'm guessing you have the 'classic' version installed on Python 2, and the Jupyter version on Python 3. There's a classic download for Python 3.4 [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#vpython), but it looks like they're pushing people towards the Jupyter version.

Comment: @PeterWood How to get all versions? When I start IPython I see version 2.7.

Comment: You need to install IPython for each python interpreter you want to use it with.

Comment: Both versions were allready installed.

Answer (score 0):

you should install ipython and Jupyter Notebook, as following

```
sudo apt-get install ipython ipython-notebook
pip install jupyter
```

And then you can use `jupyter notebook` in the terminal to start your notebook, from where you can create a new vpython notebook in your browser.
[create vpython](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKbSN.png)

and then you can write your vpython script and see the objects you created as following.
[draw a sphere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ws2Yr.png)

also you can refer to other blogs to install your jupyter notebook and so on. But make sure that you have installed vpython.