# AttributeError to run VPython within python 3.5.2 on windows

Tags: python-3.x, vpython

I'm using pyhton 3.5.2 and gonna run `VPython` on my windows machine.

I'd just installed `VPython` by `pip`, correctly.

But as I want to run the test script, as following:

```
from vpython import *
box()
```

An error will be raised:

> get_ipython().kernel.comm_manager.register_target('glow', GlowWidget)
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'kernel'

Does anybody have any idea about this issue?

Potential **unanswered** duplicate: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40200920/run-vpython-in-python3-without-jupyter-possible)

After I removed all versions and installed version 3.5 again, an error has been appeared, not to find any usable init.tcl. Furthermore, the idle editor will not be started up!

Comment: Have you multiple versions of `Python` on your machine?

Comment: @Roboticist: Yes all 2.7, 3.2, 3.4 and 3.5, together.

Comment: You better consider the possibility of conflict between all them. Just remove two middle versions, for the sake of testing whether the problem will be resolved or not...

Answer (score 1):

The conflict has changed the tcl file within your local directories. The problem with idle is, probably, the corruption of `tkInter` files.

Just copy `C:\Python35\tcl` to `C:\Python35\Lib`, entirely. Both issues must be resolved.